# What is the Flag manifold

Tags: general-topology

How does one think of flag manifold $\mathrm{U}(n)/T^n$? 
The paper that I am currently reading just tells me it can be thought of as orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Can any one help understand how?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that each point of $\mathrm{U}(n)/T^n$ can be thought of as a collection of (presumably $n$) orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$? A link to the paper might be helpful also.

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/3066339

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding also and each orthonormal vector in $\ C^n $ defined only up to phase.

Answer (score 1):

The group $\mathrm{U}(n)$ acts transitively on collections of $n$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$. (To see this, the standard basis is such a collection, and given any other collection $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$ we can put them as columns of a matrix, which will be unitary and transform the standard basis into the collection $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$. The action therefore remains transitive on equivalence classes of such collections under the relation of differing only by phase.

We can therefore identify the set of all such classes with the quotient of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ by the stabilizer of one of them, and the stabilizer of the class of the standard basis is $T^n$. The fact that we make each collection ambiguous up to phase is important here, else the stabilizer would be trivial.

(This is a particular case of a general construction - if $G$ acts transitively on a set $X$, then for each $x\in X$ there is a bijection between $X$ and $G/\operatorname{Stab}_G(x)$.)